# problem in posts category

Tags: php, categories

i need help in sql query

i have table named -- threads

contain

post_id / post_title .....

and i have categories table named

```
thread_categories
```

contain

```
cate_id / post_id
```

file.php?cate_id=20

i want get all posts in category id = 20

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to store your categories which is related to threads in a separate table.
Otherwise your query will very slow and inefficient.

You can  use current table structure and try to use the following query but I don't like it:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(provided_cat_id,REPLACE(thread_categories, '::', ','));
```

New query:

```
SELECT * FROM threads t inner join thread_categories tc on t.post_id=tc.post_id
where tc.cate_id=20;
```

Comment: Question was not what is the best way to do this.

Comment: @Senad-Meškin This is my opinion and below my realization on the current structure. So what is the cause of downvoting?

Comment: your first answer wasn't like this before

Comment: Andrej L <- thank you very very much for your help i will try and sorry because i coused problem | Senad Mesking <- thank you for your care and also sorry for because i coused small problem -- thank you all and sorry for my language i will be back after try

Comment: i was refusing make new tables because i am looking for the speed in querys .. but if the (make tables) is fast of this bad query , i will work on making new tables and leave this query -- please your ideas!

Comment: You should check two variants. But I believe it's better to use two tables. If not you can use ',' separator instead of ::. IN this case it's not neccessary to use REPLACE.

Comment: Ok i will use ',' so what is the final query? and now it became fast ? or still slow ?

Comment: FIND_IN_SET doesn't allow you to use index on this column so on big data it will slow.

Comment: Ok i will now use your idea and make new tables <- i will make new post now because i can't explain my idea here and i hope you help me in the query in the next post <- thank you very much

Comment: i updated post because i am getting It does not meet our quality standards. in the new post ..

Comment: i am testing query and will be back

Comment: Finally! i don't know how to express to you what i want say! But thank you very much Andrej and hope you did't tired of me

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from posts where YourCategoryID in (splitstring('::', thread_categories))
```

I hope this helps

Comment: How can you implement this one on pure sql?

Comment: YourCategoryID would be passed parameter like 2 so query could be '2' in (splitstring('::', thread_categories))

Comment: Thank you very much for your help i will try and be back but i have two question <- what if the post had one category without :: is that will work ? and what about the speed of query ? is that slow ?

Comment: @Senad Meskin <- thank you very much for your help but the statment did't work with me! anyway i will look in new idea because my database is big! and that will be so slow! thank you again